# How to create a rectangle pattern using Python : What's wrong with my code

Tags: python, drawrectangle

```
columns = input("Enter number of columns: ")
rows = input("Enter number of rows: ")

for r in range(rows):
    if r == 0 or r == rows - 1:
        print('* ' * columns)
    else:
        print('* ' + '  ' * (columns - 2) + '* ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rows = input("Enter number of rows: ")
```

You have maybe used languages as `C`/`C++`, in which you do something like:

```
std::cin >> var; // with var being an int
```

But in Python you have to do a `casting`, like this...

```
rows = input("Enter number of rows: ")
rows = int(rows)
```

...before using it as an integer.